# Type initializer exception 'DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiClient'

Tags: c#, docusignapi

Getting error on the call `configureApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");`

**Exception Message:**

> The type initializer for 'DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiClient' threw an exception.

Comment: Check the `InnerException` of the exception with a debugger. This exception is thrown when a static constructor fails due to a different exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue Solved.** 
The exception is due to external dependencies "RestSharp.dll" is not added. Solved by adding this one. This "RestSharp.dll" is not mentioned in the ReadMe document by DocuSign.

**Whenever you get "TypeInitializationException" exception, please read the "inner exception" to identify the problem.**

Got the more information on the following link 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(EHTypeInitialization);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true